# Реализация рекурсивной функции вычисления n-го члена последовательности по рекуррентному соотношению

Tags: функции, рекурсия

Требуется написать рекурсивную функцию вычисления n-го члена последовательности. Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать функцию.

Последовательность: [image: Последовательность]

Рекуррентное соотношение: [image: Рекуррентное соотношение]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

double func(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return func(sqrt(n - 1) * sqrt(n - 2));
}

int main() {
    cout << "n = ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "a" << n << " = " << func(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в основной строке немножко перепутали func и sqrt

```
if (n <= 2)
    return n;
return sqrt(func(n - 1) * func(n - 2));
```